# vision_bleeding not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install "tod_stub", but it failed because it tries to install "vision_bleeding" from a repo which is not found under the specified address. (https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/vision_bleeding)

Does anybody know if the repo was moved or deleted or how I could resolve the problem?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10076/vision_bleeding-not-found/) by [Cyrill](https://answers.ros.org/users/602/cyrill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-06-04**:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html might be an explanation. There's probably the so-called "Peg revision" that is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's been renamed to `vision_future` and released into unstable:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_future/trunk/

Thus, the easiest install path is to:

1. Switch to ros-unstable instead of ros-diamondback
2. `sudo apt-get install ros-unstable-vision-future`

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1